# Force concurrent chunks to go in order

Tags: fine-uploader

We've noticed that with concurrent chunking enabled, the first chunk isn't always sent first. Sometimes, the first chunk is sent last. How do we force the chunks to be sent in order while also being sent concurrently? At the very least, how do we force the first chunk to be sent first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server should not necessarily care about the order of the chunks. [Fine Uploader sends a POST when all chunks have completed](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#chunking.success.endpoint), so your server knows when to combine them. The library does in fact send the requests in order, but it's possible that they are not arriving at your server in the order they were sent. This is not something Fine Uploader has any control over, and depending on the order of requests to arrive or complete in this case is a recipe for failure.